# Connecting sites together to use DHCP

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dns, ssh-tunnel

I am working in a company with 3 sites.

- London (A) is the main site with 2 subnets separated with NAT network.
- Manchester (B) basic broadband router act as DHCP and DNS for local clients
- Dublin (C) Basic broadband router act as local DHCP and DNS for clients.

In Site A there are 2 networks,

- 1>> DHCP, DNS, AD, Xchange Server, File Share Server, local database for MS Access 2003, on server 2012 R2. Subnet: 192.168.16.X
- 2>> DHCP, DNS, Microsoft WIM Imaging Solutions. Subnet: 192.168.1.X

Is there a way to connect site B & C to Site A so they can both be connected to both WIM network and local internal Network?

At the moment there is no solution in place. Sites are not connected.

My goal is to have the same solution for site B & C as site A
If it can be achieved by VPN, site to site tunnel or any other.

Comment: This is literally the problem site to site VPN's were designed for... You will need some decent ENTERPRISE grade routers to make this work efficiently, Cisco/Meraki, ZyXEL Nebula, Sonicwall, or something similar. This question is really bigger than a simple question as you posted it...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, as i mentioned to Albin, i have a nat network in London.

Comment: I don't even see this as an issue with correct hardware and services. For example, Meraki site to site VPN's are NAT-aware and NAT-Friendly, as long as the NAT device allows VPN passthrough. We often install Meraki devices to defeat NAT as a static public IP isn't required. You could even use one Meraki device behind your NAT to route both subnets without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have two main options. Either you get a VPN capable router/firewall appliances for all three site which allow you to setup a site to site VPN connections (as acejavelin suggested in his comment), or you you use a software solution e.g. OpenVPN and pfsense  with a dedicated machine on each site which will handle the VPN/routing. Note that you will have to use a DHCP relay service if you want the DHCP server on the A site to handle all DHCP clients.

A third option we use for small satellite offices is to use a "remote AP" which is connected to our main site via VPN. This way all clients which connect to the AP at the remote site are automatically connected to the local site via VPN. That might be a viable solution for you depending on the requirements of the remote sites.

A forth option, again depending on the requirements of the remote sites, would be to connect the clients individually to the main site using a VPN connection on each client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very good. but the thing is that i have 2 network here in London. they are NATing behind the main router, is there a way to pass the nat network too ? i was looking into MPLS , the prices are cheap now. will that be preferred over VPN ?

Comment: What subnets are you using currently? 24bit? So if I understand correctly, currently there is no communication going on between the two networks in London? You can setup a/your router to route between the two networks in London, or regard one of those networks as a remote site and connect it via VPN to the main network as well, as you do with the other sites (I would suggest the first solution). Alternatively, you could put both into the same subnet.

Comment: Very good point, the problem is that i have 2 DHCP networks, one is used or office use , normal clients , the second one is for imaging solution , we just connect laptops to it use PXE and the imaging solution install our image on the laptop. I don't know how I can transfer this second one to other sites.

Comment: If you want to use the DHCP from the main/local site at the remote sites through VPN you'll need to use a DHCP relay service. But you don't necessarily need this for a site to site VPN to work.